# Advanced installation regarding to C#

Tags: c#

I want to make an advanced installer for my C# application. |I want my application continue its installation after the pre-requisites been installed.

My scenario is:

- myApplication requires .net Framework 2
- it redirects the user to the Microsoft website.
- the user installs the framework.
- the installation requires to restart the PC.

STOPPED INSTALLATION

After this step (after restarting) I want myApplication to continue the installation (go to the last stage of the installation)

Any suggestion on how I do this ?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at the nullsoft install system. Use the Modern UI theme and the DotNET macro (http://nsis.sourceforge.net/DotNET). That's everything that you are looking for prebuilt, for free, and you can be up and running with very little effort.

I've had experience releasing applications with this route and it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

Things like InstallShield, or one of the other installer creation tools would be able to handle the pre-requisite side of things for you. If you want to roll your own, then you could check for the framework, perform the various steps you mentioned to install it, then add you setup application to the [RunOnce](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137367) registry key so it starts again on startup.

Looking at something that would handle all the pre-requisites etc for you would be my choice though :-)

Answer (score 0):

Install in this order:

1. Install the .NET framework
2. Install your app.
3. Restart if needed.

You can create an installation project in VS2005/8 to handle installing your app and *any* needed dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that your compiled c# app itself will do this?  The bootstrapper compiled into a .Net exe will contain a redirect to get the framework with a working link to the microsoft website.